# Matching a string with 0 or 1 spaces

Tags: awk

I've trying to run through a bunch of data that may contain Canadian postal codes (format `A0A 0A0`) and want to print the lines that do. There may or may not be a space in the middle. I've tried the following regex:

```
awk '{if($5~/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z] +[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/){print $5}}
```

And that returns the lines that do have a space. I thought the ' +' would make it return both lines with and without. I also tried:

```
awk '{if($5~/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][ ]+[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/){print $5}}
```

but that gave the same results. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem to. I'm not sure awk sees \s as whitespace. It seems to prefer something like [:space:], but [:space:]+ also did not work.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the ?. \s? is returning only lines without the space.

Comment: Using just a space followed by ? worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plus specifies something that is repeated one or more times, which is likely not what you want. You want a question mark which will make the preceding item optional.

```
awk '{if($5~/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z] ?[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/){print $5}}
```

Comment: Thanks. My Perl brain was causing me to think differently on how those operators work.

Comment: @Ilion: The operators are the same. In addition to the `{0,1}` meaning of `?`, Perl adds a non-greediness meaning in `.*?`, for example, which AWK doesn't support. By the way, `+` is equivalent to `{1,}` and `*` is `{0,}`, for comparison

Answer (score 1):

Use a `?`

```
awk '$5~/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z] ?[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/ {print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `A0A 0A0` is split by `awk` in two fields (space by default), so you should change the `FS` (Field Separator) variable or compare `$5` with first part and `$6` with second one.

Comment: Ah yes I do actually have a different separator but cut that from my example as I was thinking it was just cruft. Of course that would change it all. Sorry for the confusion!